# SHACL check a graph for nodes of types other than a predefined set of types

Tags: rdf, shacl

Every SHACL statement has to have a target.

I have written SHACL schema for every node type I have, but that doesn't check for extra nodes of "unknown to SHACL" types in the graph.

I am looking to target all nodes to make sure they are all of a type from a predefined set.

Is there a way of doing that in simple SHACL, or do I need to learn SHACL advanced SPARQL targets for this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can express this by targeting all nodes that have an rdf:type and then check that those rdf:types are in a given enumeration. I have not tested the below snippet, but maybe it helps:

```
ex:TypeCheckShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    rdfs:comment "All subjects with any type must have a type from the provided list" ;
    sh:targetSubjectsOf rdf:type ;
    sh:property [
        a sh:PropertyShape ;
        sh:path rdf:type ;
        sh:in ( ex:Class1 ex:Class2 ... ) ;
    ] .
```

Note that doing such a sh:in enumeration may cause problems when your data graphs include other subgraphs such as the class and shape definitions themselves, but as long as you have control over the graphs that get passed into the validation it should be OK.

Instead of sh:in you could also use other constraints such as only allowing classes that are from a certain namespace, or only classes that actually have an rdf:type too.